# C# JSON deserialization of a typed dataset with foreign key constraints

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I'm attempting to serialize and deserialize typed DataSets to JSON using C# and the NewtonSoft.Json package.  This works fine except for DataSets that include a foreign key constraint and the parent table is added to the designer after the child table.  In the auto-generated Designer.cs, the parent table is added to the base DataTableCollection after the child table.

When the DataSet is serialized to JSON the child table is serialized first.  Then when deserializing the JSON back to an instance of the typed DataSet, an InvalidConstraintException is thrown ("ForeignKeyConstraint requires the child key values to exist in the parent table").

To setup a test scenario, I created a very simple typed DataSet named ChildParentDataSet.  It contains two tables.  The first table is named Child and it has one column named ParentId.  The second table is named Parent and it has one column named Id.  A foreign key is created between Parent.Id and Child.ParentId.  It's important for the Parent table to be added in the designer after the Child table.  This code results in an InvalidConstraintException on the last line:

```
ChildParentDataSet ds = new ChildParentDataSet();
ds.Parent.Rows.Add(1);
ds.Child.Rows.Add(1);
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
ChildParentDataSet? ds2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChildParentDataSet>(json);
```

My preferred approach is to handle this during deserialization by implementing my own CustomCreationConverter that initializes DataSet.EnforceConstraints to false prior to performing the deserialization, and then when deserialization is complete I would set EnforceConstraints back to true.  Here are the classes that I hoped would accomplish this:

```
public class DataSetDeserializer
{
   public static T DeserializeDataSet<T>(string json)
   {
      var ds = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new DataSetConverter<T>());
      System.Data.DataSet? dataSet = (System.Data.DataSet?)(Object?)ds;
      dataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
      return ds;
   }

   private class DataSetConverter<T> : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter<T>
   {
      public override T Create(Type objectType)
      {
         var ds = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
         System.Data.DataSet? dataSet = (System.Data.DataSet?)ds;
         dataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
         return (T)ds;
      }
   }
}
```

Then I changed the last line of my test code to use the DataSetDeserializer class rather than Newtonsoft for deserialization:

```
ChildParentDataSet? ds2 = DataSetDeserializer.DeserializeDataSet<ChildParentDataSet>(json);
```

When running this code a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException is thrown from the call to DeserializeObject.  The exception message is "Cannot populate JSON object onto type 'ChildParentDataSet'. Path 'Child', line 1, position 9.'"  I haven't been able to figure this out.

Another option I considered is to handle this during serialization rather than deserialization.  I implemented a method that sorts the tables in a DataSet such that the highest-level parent tables would be first and the lowest-level child tables would be last.  Then I serialize each table one at a time in the correct order and concatenate all the JSON strings.  That works, but critically it doesn't handle the case when a table is a parent and child of itself via a self-referential foreign key.  I can probably figure out how to handle that scenario but it would be substantially more difficult.  Plus my current implementation is quite inefficient versus serializing an entire dataset with one call.

One option that would work but I really don't want to do is to use XML instead of JSON.  It would certainly be easier since DataSets have a GetXml function, but XML is much more verbose and I'm passing this data over the wire via gRPC.  Plus it would require a very complicated redeployment of many clients and services.

I'm certainly open to suggestions.  I'm sure there are better alternatives that I haven't considered.

Edit: @Serge suggested that I post the code of `ChildParentDataSet`.  Unfortunately that's a lot of auto-generated code that is way too big to post here, but he then suggested that I create something equivalent in code.  I did so and here it is:

```
internal class ChildParentDataSet2: DataSet
{
   public DataTable Child { get; set; }
   public DataTable Parent { get; set; }

   public ChildParentDataSet2()
   {
      this.Child = this.Tables.Add("Child");
      DataColumn childColumn = this.Child.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
      this.Parent = this.Tables.Add("Parent");
      DataColumn parentColumn = this.Parent.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
      this.Parent.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { parentColumn };
      this.Child.ParentRelations.Add(parentColumn, childColumn);
   }
}
```

Strangely when using this class instead of the auto-generated one, I can deserialize it successfully when using my DataSetDeserializer and CustomCreationConverter.  So the problem apparently lies in the typed dataset which is too large to post here.

Edit 2: The ChildParentDataSet (created using the DataSet designer in Visual Studio) and the ChildParentDataSet2 (created manually as shown above) both produce the same serialized JSON: `{"Child":[{"ParentId":1}],"Parent":[{"Id":1}]}`.  Now I just need to figure out why my DataSetDeserializer works fine with ChildParentDataSet2 but not with ChildParentDataSet.  Thanks everyone for your help so far!

Edit 3: I think I figured out why my `CustomCreationConverter` worked for the `ChildParentDataSet2` that I wrote manually and not for the `ChildParentDataSet` that I created via the designer.  By using a `CustomCreationConverter` I was missing out on all the functionality that Newtonsoft provides in its own `DataSetConverter` class.  So my current solution is to create a fork of Newtonsoft's `DataSetConverter` class on Github.  That fork simply sets EnforceConstraints to false prior to deserialization and sets it back to true after.  I also created a [pull request](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/2818) but there might be performance implications or other reasons that the author won't want to include my changes.

Comment: Why do you serialize `DataSet`? There is no such thing in JSON. You should serialize something that is supported in JSON. Then it should be de-serializable in JSON. When you de-serialize to a simpler structures, you can re-create your `DataSet` in any way you want.

Comment: Since EF started, almost nobody uses DataSet anymore.  We need the code for testing. You need to post  all custom classes and the code that creates ChildParentDataSet.

Comment: @VladDX Newtonsoft provides simple examples for serializing and deserializing DataSets:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm

Comment: @Serge the auto-generated Designer.cs is too large to post here.  I'll try to find somewhere that I can upload a zip of the full project.

Comment: @u9bg214 We need the simple c# code that creates 2 tables and a relation between them. Nobody will learn a lot of code, since it is outdated technology and doesnt bring any use.

Comment: I agree that DataSets aren't used frequently but I'm supporting a very large legacy codebase.  Moving away from DataSets entirely would be a massive undertaking.  Doing what @VladDX suggested would mean writing code to translate every DataSet to a simple structure for serialization and then writing code to translate every simple structure back to a DataSet upon deserialization.  Neither approach is feasible at this point.

Comment: In Newtonsoft examples it is just simple DataSet without any relations. In your case, there is some custom `ChildParentDataSet`. It should be de-serialized in the right manner.

Comment: @VladDX I agree, that's why I'm hoping to effectively "turn off" the relations (via EnforceConstraints = false) to make deserializing simple.

Comment: Check `Path 'Child', line 1, position 9.'`. It is very specific thing.

Comment: What is this `ChildParentDataSet`? We don't know. It's essential to know to understand the problem.

Comment: @VladDX `ChildParentDataSet` is a typed DataSet created using the DataSet designer built-in to Visual Studio.  Per @Serge's suggestion I attempted to create something similar with code rather than with the designer.  Surprisingly it doesn't suffer the same problem, and the `DataSetDeserializer` class I developed works properly.  I'll post the class that I wrote to mimic `ChildParentDataSet` in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to change your DataSet constructor, adapting it to a json string. Since a json string doesn't contain any relations, you will have to add them each time.

```
public class ChildParentDataSet2 : DataSet
{
    public DataTable Child { get; set; }

    public DataTable Parent { get; set; }

    private void CreateDataSet(DataTable parent, DataTable child)
    {
        Tables.Add(child);
        this.Child = Tables[0];
        Tables.Add(parent);
        this.Parent = Tables[1];

        if (this.Parent.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            this.Parent.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            this.Child.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
        }

        var parentColumn = this.Parent.Columns["Id"];
        var childColumn = this.Child.Columns["ParentId"];

        this.Parent.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { parentColumn };
        this.Child.ParentRelations.Add(parentColumn, childColumn);

        this.Parent.TableName = "Parent";
        this.Child.TableName = "Child";
    }

    public ChildParentDataSet2(string json)
    {      
            var jObj=JObject.Parse(json);
            CreateDataSet(jObj["Parent"].ToObject<DataTable>(), jObj["Child"].ToObject<DataTable>());
    }

    public ChildParentDataSet2(JObject jObj)
    {
        CreateDataSet(jObj["Parent"].ToObject<DataTable>(), jObj["Child"].ToObject<DataTable>());
    }
    public ChildParentDataSet2()
    {
        CreateDataSet(new DataTable(), new DataTable());
    }
}
```

code for a test

```
    var ds = new ChildParentDataSet2();
    ds.Parent.Rows.Add(1);
    ds.Child.Rows.Add(1);

    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);

    var ds2 = new ChildParentDataSet2(json);
    
     ds2.Child.Rows.Add(3); // causes error key violation
```

If you like , you can create a custom converter

```
var ds2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChildParentDataSet2>(json, new DataSetConverter());


public class DataSetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(DataSet) || objectType == typeof(ChildParentDataSet2));
    }

    public override ChildParentDataSet2 ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);

        return new ChildParentDataSet2(jObj["Parent"].ToObject<DataTable>(), jObj["Child"].ToObject<DataTable>());
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

for this converter you will need to add this constructor (or replace existing)

```
    public ChildParentDataSet2(DataTable parent, DataTable child)
    {
        CreateDataSet(parent, child);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Serge.  The `ChildParentDataSet2` that I manually created is working fine with the `DataSetDeserializer` class, and it's generic to any type of DataSet.
I've got 1000+ typed DataSets all created using the VS DataSet designer and therefore have auto-generated code, so I can't use a custom constructor.
So far I haven't been able to figure out why typed DataSets created with the designer aren't playing nicely with the `DataSetDeserializer` class while my manually-created `ChildParentDataSet2` works fine.  Might have to go with my second option and handle the issue during serialization.

Comment: @u9bg214  Since you are using a typed DataSet you wrote a constructor for each type,  thousands in your case.  Your code is a mess since it is different for each data set. .  My code doesn't do anything extra,   It just changes the syntac of your constructors, makes them more clear and generic. You can turn a  createDataSet method in generic, in this case your code will be much more shorter and clear then it is now. Plus you can make it as a partial class and add some code to generated one.

Comment: Sorry I've been trying to edit my previous comment and running into StackOverflow restrictions.  As I mentioned all the code is auto-generated since these typed DataSets were created using the DataSet designer.  In theory I could go into each auto-generated Designer.cs and create a custom constructor but that would get overwritten if anyone were to make changes in the designer.

Comment: @u9bg214 Just add a partial class with the same name and put an extra constructor here. Maybe you need to change my code in order to reuse a generated one. Can you post an example of generated code?

Comment: I like your solution but manually creating a thousand partial classes for each typed DataSet isn't feasible, especially since most of those DataSets contain much more than 2 tables and have more complex parent/child relationships.  Setting EnforceConstraints to false prior to deserialization would be ideal if I could figure out why it isn't working for DataSets created using the designer.  But I'm not making any progress there so pretty sure I'll have to use a small generic method during serialization to create correctly-ordered json.

Answer (score 0):

i'm doing something similar in aspnet using dataset to json for angularjs and then back json to dataset. In case you have a foreign key constraints you need just make json conversion in the correct order. If table2 is a child of table1 it has to be oredered table1, table2 in json string. Then you put in data for each table. This is important for JsonToData conversion.. like that:

```
.cs 
  dsjson = JsonConverter.DataSetToJson(ds);    
.js on init:
      $scope.data = {"table1": [],"table2": []} // in correct order
    then fill:
      var json = jQuery.parseJSON(dsjson);
      scope.data.table1= json.table1; // 
      scope.data.table2= json.table2;
    
.cs and when you go back to dataset, also correct order
    jds = JsonConverter.JsonToData<Ds_xxx>(json);
    var ds = new Ds_xxx()
    ds.Merge(jds.table1);
    ds.Merge(jds.table2);
```

Comment: Ah, interesting approach.  You're converting the JSON string to a generic DataSet as a first step and then merging that generic DataSet with a typed DataSet one table at a time in the correct order.  I like that approach but it still requires custom code for every typed dataset.  I've still got my fingers crossed that the owner of the Newtonsoft library will merge my fork into the master.  :-)  Thanks @Izi x!